# How to include commutative tikzcd diagrams in a poster made with fancytikzposter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikzposter

I am using the [tikzposter package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter?lang=en) to create a small presentation on category theory, it is inevitable that the use of commutative diagrams must appear. In a classical document, I know how to do it and it's work, but apparently in tikzposter it doesn't work, in the words of the author:

> The default figure environment does not work within a tikzpicture. I created a new figure
> environment that can be used instead, based on the code sent by Stephan Thober:
>
> ```
> \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
> . . .
> \end{tikzfigure}
> ```

I don't know enough about tikz/tikcd to know how to add an environment that does what I want, namely to include commutative diagrams in my poster using tikzcd.

As an example, let's say I want to include the following diagram:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathcal C \arrow[dd, "F"'] &  & A \arrow[rr, "f"] \arrow[rrdd, "g\circ f"'] &  & B \arrow[dd, "g"] &  & F(A) \arrow[rr, "F(f)"] \arrow[rrdd, "F(g \circ f)"'] &  & F(B) \arrow[dd, "F(g)"] \\
                            &  &                                             &  &                   &  &                                                       &  &                         \\
\mathcal D                  &  &                                             &  & C                 &  &                                                       &  & F(C)                   
\end{tikzcd}
```

Which corresponds to this figure:

[image]

--- **EDIT** ---

I include an example of using the package with tikzcd. If you want the steps, I simply went into the OverLeaf templates, then opened [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-demonstrating-the-fancytikzposter-package/vdmkprbshnym) as an editable OverLeaf document (the link provides the package), removed all the unnecessary stuff for this example, and then keep the following code:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Scientific Poster with TikZ \qquad version 2.1}
\author{Elena Botoeva\\
  KRDB Research Centre, Free University of Bozen-Bolzano, Italy\\
  \texttt{botoeva@inf.unibz.it}
}

\begin{document}

\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \initializesizeandshifts
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{1}}{ 
        \titleblock{47}{1}
        }{
        \titleblock{47}{1.5}
    }
    
    \blocknode%
    {Example of tikz-cd}%
    {
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum semper velit, a sollicitudin elit ornare sed. Ut felis neque, ullamcorper id lacus sit amet, consectetur posuere dolor. Fusce fermentum mauris diam, a tempor justo consectetur quis. Sed luctus molestie lectus, sed gravida erat maximus sed. Proin a laoreet tellus, eget congue ex.

        \begin{tikzfigure}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \mathcal C \arrow[dd, "F"'] &  & A \arrow[rr, "f"] \arrow[rrdd, "g\circ f"'] &  & B \arrow[dd, "g"] &  & F(A) \arrow[rr, "F(f)"] \arrow[rrdd, "F(g \circ f)"'] &  & F(B) \arrow[dd, "F(g)"] \\
            &  &                                             &  &                   &  &                                                       &  &                         \\
            \mathcal D                  &  &                                             &  & C                 &  &                                                       &  & F(C)                   
        \end{tikzcd}
        \end{tikzfigure}
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc interdum semper velit, a sollicitudin elit ornare sed. Ut felis neque, ullamcorper id lacus sit amet, consectetur posuere dolor. Fusce fermentum mauris diam, a tempor justo consectetur quis. Sed luctus molestie lectus, sed gravida erat maximus sed. Proin a laoreet tellus, eget congue ex.
    }
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The important code is therefore this:

```
\blocknode
{Example of tikz-cd}
{
    ...

    \begin{tikzfigure}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \mathcal C \arrow[dd, "F"'] &  & A \arrow[rr, "f"] \arrow[rrdd, "g\circ f"'] &  & B \arrow[dd, "g"] &  & F(A) \arrow[rr, "F(f)"] \arrow[rrdd, "F(g \circ f)"'] &  & F(B) \arrow[dd, "F(g)"] \\
        &  &                                             &  &                   &  &                                                       &  &                         \\
        \mathcal D                  &  &                                             &  & C                 &  &                                                       &  & F(C)                   
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{tikzfigure}
    
    ...
}
```

In the above code, I have included the `tikzcd` environment inside `tikzfigure` (as suggested in the comments), which I had not done before. In both cases, a lot of errors are displayed, I don't know which ones to show to make it relevant, but normally the steps and the code I gave should be enough to reproduce these errors.

Comment: Welcome. Can you post a MWE where we can see how you'd use the CD with this class? What happens if you put your CD inside a `tikzfigure` environment?

Comment: Thank you. I have included sample code and steps to reproduce the errors I get. Feel free to ask if you have any other requests. @Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: You might use `ampersand replacement=\&` as an option to `\begin{tikzcd}` and `\&` instead of `&` inside. But nesting TikZ pictures is rarely going to work correctly.

Comment: Now, using `ampersand replacement=\&` it works! I didn't known about this. Thank you @egreg. Would you like to write the answer I will accept? Or is the comment enough?